# jquery drupal7 behaviors

Tags: jquery, drupal-7

i have successfully used this code in drupal 7, but do not know how i could implement the default behavior of content not shown initially. We need the content after the link to be visible only after one clicks the link.

http://mydrupalblog.lhmdesign.com/drupal-theming-jquery-basics-inc-drupal-behaviors

here is the demo of this, we need the opposite behavior of this demo,

http://www.lhmdesign.com/drupal-jquery-demo

thank you in advance

Comment: By opposite behaviour you mean hiding the content once the link is clicked? Instead of showing it?

Comment: we need the content to be originally hidden, then on click shown, actually the author has an example for drupal 6, how should it be written in order to be working for drupal 7?

Answer (score 0):

### Here ya go - [Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LNBRf/)

---SCRIPT.JS CONTENTS---

**jQuery:**

```
(function ($, Drupal, window, document, undefined) {
    Drupal.behaviors.customCode = {
        attach: function () {
            $('.myLinks').click(function () {
                $('#content').slideToggle();
            });
        }
    };
})(jQuery, Drupal, this, this.document);
```

**HTML:**

```
<div> 
    <a href="#" class="myLinks">This is your link</a>
    <div id="content" style="display: none;">This is the hidden content</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#content {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
}
div {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

This will set whatever link you reference with $('.myLinks') to listen for a click.  The content is hidden initially with inline CSS because jQuery will change it directly when it toggles.

Comment: did not work in my drupal setup, i created a page, added your code to the script folder of mytheme, added the html code to the page with plain editor but ob click had no result, nothing shown. (did not use the css code anywhere)

Comment: did you make a new js file and just paste it in there or did you add it inside the default script.js that hopefully came with your theme?  And did you add it to the .info file with `scripts[] = js/script.js`.  Obvious thing I miss all the time.  But if you put it in a separate file just as it is here it won't run because it needs to be invoked and have the `$` object passed through

Comment: the solution i am after is similar to the link provided that i have managed to make work. i pasted the whole code in script.js, added this new file to theme info, added to a page the html code and there it worked. could you please provide me with such a solution?

Comment: I'm going to edit my post with exactly what should be in script.js and let me know if it works.

Comment: no result after on click, i want to just paste this code in a drupal basic page content type.

Comment: on click i loose all content, all content is hidden

Comment: Do me a favor and put the code into a jsbin or jsfiddle so I can track down the cause with you

Comment: ok got it to work on my end (and on my drupal site).  Try this:  1) Make a new file called toggle.js in your theme folder, 2) put this code in it exactly `(function ($) {$('.myLinks').click(function (){$('#content').slideToggle();});})(jQuery);` 3) set theme.info to have the old script file AND the new one (not sure if order matters but put the new one after the old), 4) make sure your HTML IDs/classes match, 5) flush all caches and refresh.  I just want to make sure this works in general.  If it does, we'll continue with the `Drupal.behaviors` format

Comment: made this new script, and added this <div> 
    <a href="#" class="myLinks">This is your link</a>
    <div id="content" style="display: none;">This is the hidden content</div>
</div> code to my page, still no result

Comment: Is it a page I can access online?

Comment: lol change the ID of the hidden content.  there's already a box on that page with that ID.  DOM specificity rules restrict selecting an ID to one element and it's whichever one comes first on the page.  `<a href="#" class="myLinks">Show hidden content</a><div id="hidden-content">Your hidden content here</div>`

Comment: still though, what i am looking for is the opposite behaviour: once we click the link, the hidden content shows up, instead of hiding

Comment: Once you change the javascript to point to the new ID and have the new ID on the HTML it will work the way you intended it to.

Comment: disregard that it seems your site has a bit of conflicts i'll check it out real quick